# "Playing instrument according to what's written in the magazine"

Tags: grammar

To say "I played violin according to what's written in the magazine", my intuition is:

```
音楽雑誌に載るようにバイオリンを演奏した。
```

however, reading from the text above it sounds really weird, as I didn't "play" the way the music article was "appeared" (A載るようにBを演奏する). On the other hand, 踊るように演奏する sounds perfectly fine.

what would be a more natural way to express?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you could say:

> 雑誌に載っ**ている**ように演奏した。
>   雑誌に書かれ**ている**ように/書い**てある**ように演奏した。

載るように演奏する might sound like "perform so that it will be in the magazine" (since the plain form of a verb can be the future tense), or "perform as if appearing(?)" (like 踊るように演奏する can mean "perform as if dancing.")

I think it'd be a bit more natural to say:

> 雑誌に載っている[通]{とお}りに演奏した。
>   雑誌に書かれている通りに/書いてある通りに演奏した。
>   雑誌の通りに演奏した。

cf. 楽譜/譜面の通りに演奏する・楽譜/譜面[通]{どお}りに演奏する

Answer (score 5):

**[dictionary form] + ように** doesn't have "according to/in the same way as" meaning. It means:

- as if (it were): 踊るように演奏する, 燃えるように広がる, 探るように尋ねる
- in order to; aiming for: 動くようにする, 当たるように祈る, やせるように努力する
- likewise; so does: あなたが絵で世界を表現するように、私は音楽で表現する

The reason is very simple. Dictionary form (= simple present) basically describes what about to happen, that is, not yet realized *at this very moment*. You can't imitate what hasn't shown yet.

To translate "I played violin according to what's written in the magazine":

- **V + ている + ように**: 雑誌に載っているように～演奏した (you had the magazine when you were playing)
- **V + ていた + ように**: 雑誌に載っていたように～演奏した (you had seen the magazine previously and didn't have it at that time)

There's one more form you can use (but not in this case):

- **V + た + ように**: 彼女が演奏したようにバイオリンを演奏した

Why you can't use this is because 雑誌に載る isn't the action of playing violin.